# Chrome devtools extension background page to panel

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am having no luck passing a message from the background page to the panel. There are plenty of examples and documentation but it appears to not work from an event.

Here's the background page's listener - standard stuff.

```js
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    
    var extensionListener = function (message, sender, sendResponse) {

        if(message.tabId && message.content) {

                //Evaluate script in inspectedPage
                if(message.action === 'code') {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(message.tabId, {code: message.content});

                //Attach script to inspectedPage
                } else if(message.action === 'script') {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(message.tabId, {file: message.content});

                //Pass message to inspectedPage
                } else {
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(message.tabId, message, sendResponse);
                }

        // This accepts messages from the inspectedPage and 
        // sends them to the panel
        } else {
            port.postMessage(message);
        }
        sendResponse(message);
    }

    // Listens to messages sent from the panel
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(extensionListener);

    port.onDisconnect.addListener(function(port) {
        chrome.extension.onMessage.removeListener(extensionListener);
    });

});
```

This code works fine in all the "textbook" examples. But in this context, it sends a message and the event listener does not pick it up.

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changes, tabObject) {
    if(changes.status && changes.status === "complete") {
        if(tabObject.url) {
            var command = 'console.log("url is ' + tabObject.url + '");';
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: command});

            //** Trying to trigger message in background, which will pass message to panel.html */
            // THIS DOES NOT WORK!!! //
            var message = {content: "hello console"};
            chrome.extension.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }    
  });
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or know why the messages are not picked up within the onUpdated event?

This is the code in the panel that should be triggered. It works in other scenarios.

```js
(function createChannel() {
    //Create a port with background page for continous message communication
    var port = chrome.extension.connect({
        name: "Channel between inspected page" //Given a Name
    });

    // Listen to messages from the background page
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {

      document.getElementById("textareaconsole").value = message.content;
    });

}());
```

If you're curious, I'm attempting to disable the devtools extension if it isn't a specific domain. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to send data to the panel from the background.

Comment: Then simply use the port.

Comment: Thank you! That was the fix. When my code was moved into OnConnect where the port is accessible, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to move my event code into the chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener event where it can reference the passed-in port.

```js
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
...
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changes, tabObject) {
        if(changes.status && changes.status === "complete") {
            if(tabObject.url) {
                var command = 'console.log("url is ' + tabObject.url + '");';
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: command});

                // This passes the message from the background page to the panel!!! //
                var message = {content: "hello console"};
                port.postMessage(message);
            }
        }   
    });
```

Thanks to [woxxom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)